# How does css max-width work on mobile devices?

Tags: html, mobile, css

I am getting a bit confused here - I have a css style with the following:

```
@media (max-width: 855px) {
    #page {
        //declarations
    }
}
```

This works alright on my desktop, the browser sets the style when I resize the window, as it is declared. However I cannot seem to make it work on mobile devices. Testing this on an iphone 4 the layout is not set correctly. I assumed that if the display of the iphone is 640 x 960 px that it would work alright. What am I missing?

Comment: On desktop, that should max out at 855px, on a mobile, that should fill the screen 100%. Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: Here is a link: http://www.pixelhood.com/fb/ I would assume the menu items would be in vertical layout on mobile but they are not.

Comment: That resolution you mentioned seems a little high for an iPhone.

Comment: It has nothing to do with iphone, however it should work on the iphone as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this to your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your meta with `"viewport"` before `</head>` tag

and add media query in at your CSS

```
@media (max-width: YOUR_WIDTH_VALUE) {

}
```